# Git: Using merge=ours strategy from command line

Tags: git, merge

Sometimes, I would like to tell git to use a certain branch's version in the case of a conflict.

I can do this by running: 
`git config --global merge.ours.driver true` and then adding a .gitattributes file with content `pom.xml merge=ours`

Is it possible to do this without the need to change the git config or using .gitattributes? I'd like to specifiy it inline, if that's possible?

So, something like 
`git merge develop <?? pom.xml merge=ours??>`

To give some context, in these special cases the poms will be in conflict (I'll change both the release and develop versions). I'm trying to automate this part, so there'll be limited opportunity to manually inspect results. I don't want to use .gitattributes because there are times when I genuinely do need to resolve conflicts (real changes, not just a version number)

Comment: What about `git merge -s ours develop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command-line flag with that exact effect.

There *is* a way to do it, but it's rather manual and exposes the flaw in `merge.ours.driver`.  Suppose that you run `git merge develop` and there *is* a conflict in `pom.xml`.  This is what you will see:

```
$ git merge develop
... message about conflict in pom.xml
$ git status
Unmerged paths:
    ...
    pom.xml
```

At this point, to resolve `pom.xml` as `ours`, you can simply run:

```
$ git checkout --ours pom.xml && git add pom.xml
```

because the conflicted merge puts *all three* versions of `pom.xml` into the index, and `git checkout --ours` copies your (`HEAD`) version rather than their (`MERGE_HEAD`, i.e., `develop`) version to the work-tree, after which `git add` resolves the conflict.

Suppose, though, that `git merge develop` finds that *you* did *not* change `pom.xml` and they *did* change `pom.xml`.  In this case, Git will take *their* version of `pom.xml`: you won't get a conflict in the file.  If there are no other conflicts, you will not even have the opportunity to overwrite their `pom.xml` with your own `pom.xml`: Git will go ahead and make the merge commit on its own.

**But that's also what happens even with an `ours` driver.**  If there is *no* conflict because we did not touch the file, Git just takes *theirs*.  The `ours` driver only takes effect if *both branch tips* changed the file, with respect to the common merge base commit.

In this case, the `ours` driver is more powerful than, e.g., `-Xours`, so there are a few cases where Git will say "auto-merging" and succeed, where an `ours` driver would skip the merge entirely.  Ultimately, though, there are several corner cases to be concerned with here, and `merge.ours.driver` only handles one of them.

#### What you can do about this, in the end

In the end, there are two approaches to deal with this:

- Run merges with `--no-commit`, so that Git stops before committing the result.  You can then *test* the merge and make sure it is good, and if necessary, fix any problems before committing.
- Allow the merge to commit, but *test* the result.  If it is wrong, immediately fix it (with a followup fix-commit, or with `git commit --amend` to replace the merge commit at the tip of your branch with a new and different merge commit).

Note that both the `--no-commit`-and-fix and the `--amend` methods produce what some might call an [evil merge](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_evil_merge).  (Some might *not* call it that, especially if the merge itself produced, or would produce, a conflict.)  It's up to you, making the merge, to decide whether this is better or worse than some alternative.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer. To give some context, in these special cases the poms _will_ be in conflict (I'll change both the release and develop versions).  I'm trying to automate this part, so there'll be limited opportunity to manually inspect results.  I don't want to use .gitattributes because there are times when I genuinely do need to resolve conflicts (real changes, not just a version number)